# vba paste sheet1 values and keep original source color but not font and other formats...?

Tags: excel, vba

I have up to 6 cells with potential data coming from 6 different places. I am trying to get only the first three cells with data transferred to another sheet WITH THE ORIGINAL SHEET1 COLOR but not FORMAT

```
 Sub Transfer_Data()


Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

what happens is it displays the sheet2 format and color when im trying to keep sheet1.
i tried this also but its keeping sheet1 formats.....

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        j = j + 1
    End If

If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color`?

Comment: no doesn't work still comes up as black

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to keep the cell's colour, not the font'text's colour. Try: `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Font.Color = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Font.Color` (note this will only work if all the text has the same colour)

Comment: thanks and if all the text is not the same color?

Comment: It might be easier to get the format of the cell in Sheet2, copy the cell from sheet1into it, then apply the original formatting back on it.

Comment: never mind it works. as long as each cell is one color but a1 and a2 can be diffrent colors. thanks

Comment: Yes, by "note this will only work if all the text has the same colour" I mean "note this will only work if all the text **in a given cell** has the same colour". I'll post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have VBA apply the formatting to the cell:

```
Sub Transfer_Data()


Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Font.Color = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Font.Color
        j = j + 1
    End If

If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that this will only work if all the text in a given cell has the same colour